# ExtJS 4 GridView - How to get cell's td or div?

Tags: view, grid, cell, extjs4

In GridPanel, we all know that we can specify `renderer` in a column configuration to have customized cell. Now there is this special case which I need to build a customized visual progress bar (canvas) to be drawn into a cell, my question is **how to get the `el` of the cell**?

In the renderer callback, available values are `value`, `metadata`, `record`, `rowIndex`, `columnIndex`, `store`, and `view`. I have tried `view.getNode` or `view.getCell` with no luck still.

Thanks you in advance!

/Lionel

**EDIT**

After some further diggings, I realized my nodes are in fact not ready by the time the renderer is called, that is, the `view.getNode` and `view.getCell` is in fact working, but delayed (it returns null all the time)

A workaround is to use `setTimeout` and renders the elements after the nodes is ready. This is definitely not the best way dealing the case. Any suggestions are welcome anyway :)

/Lionel

Comment: I believe there is a way to deal with this case. But just in case this is not the correct way, any suggestions are welcome too.

Comment: try to use dom query by css class

Comment: No cleaner way? I thought they would expose the el somewhere in the `view`

Comment: I think it can't be done in renderer. u can do like this plugin,http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135880-Ext.ux.grid.column.ActionButtonColumn

Comment: I have done my progress bar (canvas) in the cell. `view.getNode` is working by adding delays. I will post my answer up along with the progress bar later once I cleaned up the code. /Lionel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that the answer to this question is to use `setTimeout` to simulate some delays so the nodes can be added correctly after some delay.

This is my `renderer`

```
renderer = function (v, meta, rec, r, c, store, view) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        var row = view.getNode(rec);

        //Capturing the el (I need the div to do the trick)
        var el = Ext.fly(Ext.fly(row).query('.x-grid-cell')[c]).down('div');

        //All other codes to build the progress bar
    }, 50);
};
```

Ugly, but it works. If no other answers, I will accept it as a valid answer in the next two days.

Cheers

/Lionel

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly neater solution, avoiding the need for a `setTimeout` call.

Basically my `renderer` adds a `class` to the cell that I want custom content in, then I use a combination of `listeners` to render custom content to that cell after the grid is present on the page.

```
renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
  metaData.tdCls = metaData.tdCls + ' customContentCell';
  return '';
}
```

On the grid I add an `afterrender` listener that in turn adds a `refresh` listener to the gridview. I would have liked to use viewready or some other event but that doesn't appear to work in the version of ext I am using, 4.0.2a.

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function (grid) {
        var view = this.getView();
        if (view)
          view.on('refresh', gridRenderCustomContent, this);
    }
}
```

In that `refresh` function I then loop through all the records and render the content out into the cell. Something like the following, which simply adds a ext container to the cell, should work as a basis.

```
var gridRenderCustomContent = function () {

    var recordIdx, colEl, chart, record, ganttHolder;

    for (recordIdx = 0; recordIdx < grid.store.getCount(); recordIdx++) {
        record = grid.store.getAt(recordIdx);
        holder = Ext.DomQuery.select('.customContentCell', grid.view.getNode(recordIdx));
        if (holder.length) {
            colEl = holder[0];
            colEl.innerHTML = '';
            var customContentContainer = new Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
                style: 'height: 30px',
                items:[ ... ],
                renderTo: holder
            });
        }
    }
};
```